# Parsing string to JsonObject in Java

Tags: java, json, jackson

In my Java project I am constantly getting a string input such as "{type=01010201, capacity=700, auth_method=01, auth_no=090713}"

When I am trying to parse this string like below, it seems to fail

```java
JsonObject tot_payload = null;
try {
    tot_payload = new JsonObject(obj.getString("data"));
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error("record in json parsing error");
}
```

I understand that this is due to the fact that I am missing the spaces for the string.
My application receives a variety of different strings like this and I was wondering if there would be any efficient way of turning such string into a json object.

Comment: But where is your `data` atrribute? As far as I see, your input has `type, capacity, auth_method, auth_no`, but you're trying to fetch the key that is not inside this object.

Comment: I think "tot_payload" object must be string and      tot_payload=obj.getString("data");

Comment: can you add `obj` variable value

Comment: Contrary to your assumption, the JSON format does not require spaces, but it expects colons instead of equal signs.

Comment: Please name the used JSON library in your question.

Comment: What is obj.getString()? A JsonObject?

Comment: @JensPiegsa I am using Jackson, but I am open to using other libraries as well. I guess I can replaceAll("=", ":"). Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: @mutantkeyboard The value that I mentioned is the result I get from obj.getString("data"), It is a json inside a json

Comment: Please do not provide such additional information as comment. Always always always update your question instead, and read [mcve] carefully UPFRONT to ensure that your question contains the necessary information BEFORE hitting submit.

Comment: And unrelated: learn about java naming conventions. Variables/fields go camelCase, the "_" is for SOME_CONSTANT only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that it is `org.json.JSONObject`, preprocessing your input into actual JSON format should solve the problem:

```java
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class JSONObjectLT {
    
    @Test
    void parseString() throws JSONException {
        
        final String input = "{type=01010201, capacity=700, auth_method=01, auth_no=090713}";
        
        // only works if keys/values do not contain equal signs
        final String preprocessed = input.replace('=', ':');
        final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(preprocessed);

        assertThat(json.getString("type")).isEqualTo("01010201");
        assertThat(json.getInt("capacity")).isEqualTo(700);
    }
}
```

Maven dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-json-org</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.2</version>
</dependency>
```